# Simulate z/OS FINDREP

Tags: sorting, dfsort

Is it possible to replace FINDREP with options STARTPOS, ENDPOS with somthings else in DFSORT or MFSORT ?

Example: `OUTREC|INREC FINDREP=(IN=C'CHARS',OUT=C'CHARS')`

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? You don't specify STARTPOS or ENDPOS in your example, and changing CHARS to CHARS is pointless. What would you like to replace it with, and why?

Comment: I work on z/OS migration and FINDREP is not supported in MFSORT(microfocus) I want to replace it with somthigs else in SORT ?

Answer (score 1):

From the Micro Focus documentation relating to MFSORT and MFJSORT:

> Note: MFJSORT and MFSORT are updated with new features on a regular basis but they do not offer a complete emulation of third-party sort utilities. If there are particular features that you need to use, please contact SupportLine to establish if they are available in MFJSORT or MFSORT.

Presumably Micro Focus, or someone, has been involved in planning the migration from z/OS? This should have included an analysis of the work required for providing equivalence to SORT/ICETOOL steps. If not, there may be considerable work which hasn't been budgeted for.

If `FINDREP` is not available in either MFSORT or MFJSORT (check with SupportLine, as Micro Focus suggests) and if they cannot be made available (if Micro Focus have missed this, it may be possible to apply pressure on that issue) the you do need an alternative.

If is possible, especially since you mention the use of STARTPOS and ENDPOS, that CHANGE, which is available from a Micro Focus product according to this linke: http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.edtest%2FHRFLRHSORT2U.html, which shows this code:

```
Sort C'cyymmdd' 
     SORT FIELDS=(1,7,BI,A)        * sort C'cyymmdd' 
     use mfs110a.in org ls record (f 40)
    * Transform C'cyymmdd' to C'yyyymmdd' 
     OUTFIL OUTREC=(1,1,CHANGE=(2, * change C'c' as follows:
                      C'0',C'19',  *   C'0' to C'19' 
                      C'1',C'20',  *   C'1' to C'20' 
                      C'2',C'21'), *   C'2' to C'21' 
                      NOMATCH=(C'99')
                    2,6)           * copy C'yymmdd' 

     give sortout.dat
```

Note that you have "extra" commands required for MFSORT/MFJSORT (like the `use` and `give` and the inclusion of a program-name.

Judging from the above code, Micro Focus have not made `IFTHEN` available. That will have substantial impact on anything remotely "complex" that is currently being done with DFSORT steps or ICETOOL steps with `USING`.

Micro Focus do support E15 and E35 "exit"s. That means you can write a program to make changes at the input stage, and at the output stage. You tell MFSORT/MFJSORT to use that program(s) and you implement missing functionality. On the Mainframe those exits can be written in Enterprise COBOL. I assume that in your new environment they can be written in Micro Focus COBOL. If so, FINDREP can be done with INSPECT. But, given that you want to use STARTPOS and ENDPOS you will/may need numerous exit-programs.

You should also check, if your systems use ICETOOL, that all the operators that you use are available under Micro Focus's "emulation".

The good news is that the Operating System you are migrating to will have lots of tools which will be able to effect coding which is not supported, but that really needs to be assessed and budgeted.

DFSORT is exceptionally fast, especially at IO, but not limited to that. You may expect different relative timings for your replacements, especially if you need exit-programs or further processing with "shell" programs on your new OS. Again this should have been considered prior to this point, but the worry would be that it has not.

If yours is other than a small z/OS system, be aware that you will be in for many shocks as the new distributed system fails to "scale" how you imagine.

If you are migrating yourselves, rather than a Micro Focus project team, you will almost certainly need the support of additional specialist(s). Even with a Micro Focus project team, if you have "complex" SORT steps, additional specialist support will give you huge benefits.

Answer (score 0):

AHLSORT is an alternative to MFSORT that fully supports the DFSORT FINDREP command.